# Initialize date and time array C#

Tags: c#

Please how do I initialize a date and time array?

I have different bookings in this format

| Name | ID | DateOfbooking | Starttimeofprogram | durationofprogram |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | 2345 | 10/06/2021 | 10:45AM | 45mins |

In my code, I am trying to create an array of time with dateTime, but the dateTime also displays "date" even in the starttimeofprogram column and also when I try to create for only date, it also displays time in the dateofbooking column. How do I fix this?

I need only date in the dateofbooking column and only time in the starttimeofprogram column.

This is the code I'm using.

```
DateTime[] DT1 = new DateTime[]
{
    new DateTime(2021,08,12,10,45,00), 
    new DateTime(2021,08,13,13,00,00), 
    new DateTime(2021,08,19,7,00,00), 
    new DateTime(2021,08,25,15,00,00), 
    new DateTime(2021,08,21,16,45,00),
};
```

Comment: How are you displaying these values? Please be aware that a `DateTime` is exactly what it says, it's a date AND a time. Unless you customize how the value is formatted, it will display both components.

Comment: Please how do I format it? I'm really new to programming and I'm still sort of clueless about it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I format a DateTime? in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398108/how-do-i-format-a-datetime-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

Various format formats of the DateTime object are available in the C# programming language:

| Format | Result |
| --- | --- |
| `DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")` | 05/29/2015 |
| `DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy")` | Friday, 29 May 2015 |
| `DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm tt")` | 05:50 AM |

For more information, you can visit the [C# DateTime Format](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/date-and-time-format-in-c-sharp-programming1) link.

Comment: The `DateTime` object's `.ToString` method can produce _strings_ in a variety of formats (note: `string`), but `DateTime` itself has no textual format. It simply stores a `long` value: `Ticks`.

Comment: what's more ridiculous is the format command, while overlapping some of the commands in that list, also supports different ones as well.

Comment: Here's my understanding from the question: to show different fields of the same `DateTime` object (such as date in the `DateOfBooking` column, time in the `StartTimeOfProgram` column) in different columns in a table.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question in the title, there is no datatypes for just "date" or "time" so you would need to create your own or simply create two string arrays.

To resolve the problem you are mentioning with displaying the values, you need to manually define the format for when the datetime value is converted to string.

Your code will basically be calling .ToString() when you try to display it in your column. Instead you want to provide this method with the format you want it converted into:

```
// The first array item as a date
DT1[0].ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");

// The first array item as a time
DT1[0].ToString("hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

For more information regarding DateTime.ToString() formats: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/date-and-time-format-in-c-sharp-programming1

Comment: @Josh no problem. I made a mistake on the time string format, edited my answer with the correct one. 
Please mark my reply as your accepted answer and upvote it if it's solved your issue. Thanks!
[See here for how to accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)